Заголовки date/expires/last-modified
Хотелось бы точно знать, что означают данные заголовки. В интернете все как то расплывчато...
В заголовке ответа:

date - необходимо указывать дату когда новость была опубликована?
expires - необходимо указывать дату на перед, сообщить поисковому
боту дату после которой роботу необходимо снова посетить данную
страницу?
last-modified - сообщить дату последнего изменения новости, для того
чтобы бот смог сравнить со значением предыдущего посещения. И если
отличается, проиндексирует по новой?

Верно?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Date https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified
